# In R how do I reference\lookup in the cdf of standard normal distribution table?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am assuming R has this built-in. How do I reference it?

Comment: `dnorm(x)` gives the density function $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$. If you want the density for mean $\mu$ and *standard deviation* $\sigma$, then you can pass these as the second and third parameters, respectively. Use `pnorm` in the same way to get the cumulative distribution function. `qnorm` gives the quantile function (inverse cdf). Typing `?pnorm` will give some more informatio on all three.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The functions you are looking for are either `dnorm`, `pnorm` or `qnorm`, depending on exactly what you are looking for.

`dnorm(x)` gives the density function at `x`.

`pnorm(x)` gives the probability that a random value is less than `x`.

`qnorm(p)` is the inverse of `pnorm`, giving the value of `x` for which getting a random value less than `x` has probability `p`.

See the help page for these functions to see how to change the parameters and values.